# Delete rows if combination of two column values is satisfied in python

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, row

I've below data: I need to delete all rows which have a combination of (ColX='F' and ColY='Y'). 
I'm trying the below different codes as suggested by below answers.

1. df = df[(df.ColX != 'F')&(df.ColY !='Y')]
   But this code is removing all rows with (ColX=P and ColY=Y) along with (ColX=F and ColY=Y).  I need rows with (ColX=P and ColY=Y) in my data.
2. mask = (df.ColX == 'F') & (df.ColY == 'Y')
     df[~mask]
   This code is not removing any of the rows which I want to remove.

   3.mask = (df.ColX == 'F') | (df.ColY == 'Y')
   df[~mask]
   This code is removing all rows with (ColX=P and ColY=Y) along with (ColX=F and ColY=Y).  I need rows with (ColX=P and ColY=Y) in my data.

Any inputs are highly appreciated. Thank you!

```
 line_date      ColX       ColY    ColZ   rating        rw    

 2007-03-31       P         Y        56     1.000000  56.000000
 2007-03-10       P         Y        67     1.000000  67.000000
 2007-02-10       F         Y        66     1.000000  66.000000
 2007-01-13       2                  83     0.880678  73.096278
 2006-12-23       2         Y        88     0.793033  69.786942
 2006-11-09       F                  52     0.636655  33.106077
 2006-10-22       P                  66     0.581946  38.408408
 2006-09-29       F         Y        70     0.518825  36.317752
```

Comment: df = df[~(df.ColX == 'F')&(df.ColY =='Y')]

Comment: Maybe you mean df.ColY and not a.ColY in the second part of your conditional?

Comment: Swap & for | operator and it should be okay. For future reference, check de Morgan's laws (de Morgan's law in this case: negation of (A AND B) is logically equal to (negation of A OR negation of B).

Comment: Hi Todd, that was a typo. I'm using the right data frame name but not getting the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code gave me my expected dataset:

```
filter_df=df[ ~(df['ColY'].str.contains("Y") & df['ColX'].str.contains("F")) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mask = (df.ColX == 'F') & (df.ColY == 'Y')
df[~mask]
```

Output:

```
    line_date ColX ColY  ColZ    rating         rw
0  2007-03-31    P    Y    56  1.000000  56.000000
1  2007-03-10    P    Y    67  1.000000  67.000000
3  2007-01-13    2  NaN    83  0.880678  73.096278
4  2006-12-23    2    Y    88  0.793033  69.786942
5  2006-11-09    F  NaN    52  0.636655  33.106077
6  2006-10-22    P  NaN    66  0.581946  38.408408
```

Or, because I am a little confused what your output should be.

```
mask = (df.ColX == 'F') | (df.ColY == 'Y')
df[~mask]
```

Output:

```
    line_date ColX ColY  ColZ    rating         rw
3  2007-01-13    2  NaN    83  0.880678  73.096278
6  2006-10-22    P  NaN    66  0.581946  38.408408
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me Scott, I'm getting rows with Y and F combinations even after applying the above logic.

Comment: Okay then try to replace the & with |.  `mask = (df.ColX == 'F') | (df.ColY == 'Y')`

Comment: mask = (df.ColX == 'F') | (df.ColY == 'Y')- This code is removing all rows with (ColX=P and ColY=Y) along with (ColX=F and ColY=Y). I need rows with (ColX=P and ColY=Y) in my data.                                                                  mask = (df.ColX == 'F') & (df.ColY == 'Y')-This code is not removing any of the rows which I want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`DataFrame.query()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html?highlight=query):

```
In [20]: df.query("ColX != 'F' or ColY != 'Y'")
Out[20]:
    line_date ColX ColY  ColZ    rating         rw
0  2007-03-31    P    Y    56  1.000000  56.000000
1  2007-03-10    P    Y    67  1.000000  67.000000
3  2007-01-13    2  NaN    83  0.880678  73.096278
4  2006-12-23    2    Y    88  0.793033  69.786942
5  2006-11-09    F  NaN    52  0.636655  33.106077
6  2006-10-22    P  NaN    66  0.581946  38.408408
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me Max, I'm getting rows with Y and F combinations even after applying the above logic.